# How to import a namespace with using 'require'?

Tags: javascript, module, coffeescript, typescript, gruntjs

In some code I'm working on I have a mixture of Coffeescript, Javascript and Typescript files.

In my Typescript file, I access the type definitions using

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
import {FooA, FooB} from "foo";

var a:FooA = new FooA() // etc...
```

This results in the Javascript

```
var foo_1 = require("foo");
var a = new foo_1.FooA();
```

Which is fine. However, my workflow is such that I don't use a module system. All the non-JS files are handled by Grunt and compiled to JS and then bundled together.

Ideally I would want my Typescript to compile to

```
var a = new FooA();
```

as I can guarantee they would be in the global namespace.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally I would want my Typescript to compile to ... as I can guarantee they would be in the global namespace. How can I do this?

I am sure you know that `global` is bad and susceptible to subtle ordering issues (beyond just name collision) : [some notes](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md)

That said. A file will become a module *as soon as you have a root level `import` or `export`* ([some docs](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html)).

So :

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
import {FooA, FooB} from "foo";

var a:FooA = new FooA() // etc...
```

Should be something like:

```
/// <reference path="foo.d.ts" />
var a:FooA = new FooA() // etc...
```

i.e. `FooA` should be available globally. You need to review your `foo.d.ts`. This will help: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html